# javafx + controlsfx glyphicon - unexpected behaviour when .text is set to font-weight: bold

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, controlsfx

I am using JavaFX with ControlsFX Glyph icons and fontawesome.

It works nicely with the default JavaFX Modena theme.

But when I add the yellowOnBlack CSS for high contrast, the icons turns to weird font shapes.

The Glyph source code explicitly sets the font family which I am passing "FontAwesome". Its sets thru Label.setFontFamily().

The control looks like this on Modena:

```
ToggleButton[id=btnHamburger, styleClass=toggle-button]''
    Glyph@72cc2cbd[styleClass=label glyph-font]''
        Text[text="", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=FontAwesome, family=FontAwesome, style=Regular, size=14.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0x333333ff]
```

When I add the yellowOnBlack it looks like this:

```
ToggleButton[id=btnHamburger, styleClass=toggle-button]''
    Glyph@3bd84c6d[styleClass=label glyph-font]''
        Text[text="", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=12.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0xffff00ff]
```

It is overriding the font-family, which is weird because it was set thru the .setFontFamily().

That's because yellowOnBlack sets this CSS:

```
.text,
.text-input {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

It works if i do this:

```
.glyph-font .text {
    -fx-font-weight: normal;
    -fx-font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

But I cannot fix the -fx-font-family to "FontAwesome" because it's optional on the Glyph constructor.

Any alternative ideas to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled over the same problem. In my case it was enough to remove the "label" style class from the Glyph object:

```
glyph.getStyleClass().remove("label");
```

As a consequence, none of my style rules, in which some font property was set, were applied to the glyph resulting in the correct rendering of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a subclass and overriden the setFontFamily():

```
@Override
public void setFontFamily(String family) {
    setStyle(String.format("-fx-font-family: \"%s\"", family));
}
```

It worked. Not the best solution tho.